# JSP takes too long to show recently updated image

Tags: image, jsp, upload

I have a JSP page that calls a servlet->EJB to save a book resgistry and upload its cover image. Everything works properly. The image is uploaded to the right folder, etc.

The problem is that the image is not immediately shown if requested by another JSP page. It takes a couple of minutes to "be done".

Is there some configuration I need to set?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: Sounds like its a browser cache problem. You could simply add a random string to the image url to have it reloaded each time. Or use http headers to prevent caching when delivering the image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dirk. I don't think it's a browser cache problem cause the image is new (it's added after a new book registration). In my JSP page I just see the img space, as if there was no such image in my server (which is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

Dont copy the image to a folder, stream the image directly from a servlet. http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html

Comment: Thanks shizzledizzle. I did change my upload method to InputStream, but it didn't work. Btw I'm using the org.apache.common.FileUpload package to read my multipart form and upload the image. I'd like to emphasize that everything works properly, the only problem is that it still taking to long to the image to be shown in the JSP page.